# How to enlist my custom profile with the pre-existing ones

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-9800

I wanted to make my own custom profile, and want to enlist it into existing ones..

Once the client will select my profile, The application will put certain business

activities.

Comment: we can change our profile setting but we can't create our own custom profiles

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a custom profile and add it to the list of default profiles.

Comment: Thanks for reply, is there any class in rim repository other than net.rim.device.api.system.Alert, to work with custom profile like things.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String ab=(String) tb2.getText();
            Toast.makeText(ProfileSetActivity.this, ab, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           if(ab.equals("ON"))am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
           else am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        }
        });       
        final ToggleButton tb3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
        tb3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
       {`enter code here`
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String ab=(String) tb3.getText();
```